# Implementing favoriting a listing logic on React/Redux e-commerse store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

So I am working on favoriting a listing in an e-commerce store. 
**The concept**
Whereby when a user wants to save a listing, they just click on a heart icon and it turns from grey to black to that specific item.

I have tried making the heart icon as a single component by itself, it interacts with the backend quite fine, but when I try to save a single listing all listings turn black.

Save icon component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import { Icon } from "antd";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { fetchSave, fetchSaves, saveListing } from "../../redux/actions/saves";
import authHelper from "../../helpers/auth";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

class Save extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (authHelper()) {
      const { fetchSave, product } = this.props;

      fetchSave(product);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleSaveListing = () => {
    if (authHelper()) {
      const { saveListing, product } = this.props;

      saveListing(product);
      fetchSave(product);
    } else {
      toast.warn("Please login to save product");
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { saved, save, product } = this.props;
    return (
      <Link className="has-text-right hover-effect" onClick={this.handleSaveListing}>
        <Icon
          type="heart"
          style={{
            fontSize: "25px",
            padding: "5px",
            marginLeft: "55%",
            color: `${saved ? "#000000" : "#ebeaea"}`
          }}
        />
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

Save.propTypes = {
  saved: PropTypes.bool,
  save: PropTypes.object
};

Save.defaultProps = {
  saved: false,
  save: {}
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  saved: state.saves.saved,
  save: state.saves.save
});

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { fetchSave, saveListing }
  )(Save)
);
```

Single Listing component

```
import React from "react";
import { Divider, Icon } from "antd";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import moment from "moment";
import momentTimeZone from "moment-timezone";
import amountFormatter from "../../../helpers/amountFormatter";
import SaveIcon from "../../containers/Save";

const Product = ({ product, handleAddToCart }) => (
  <section className="column is-full-mobile is-two-thirds-tablet is-half-desktop is-one-quarter-widescreen is-one-quarter-fullhd">
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-image">
        <figure className="image is-3by2">
          <img src={product.images[0]} alt={product.name} />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div className="card-content">
        <div className="media-content">
          <Link to={`/products/${product._id}`} className="title is-5">
            {product.name}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="media-content">
          Ksh. {amountFormatter(product.amount)}
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <span className="subtitle is-7">
          {moment(
            momentTimeZone.tz(product.createdAt, "Africa/Nairobi"),
            "YYYYMMDD"
          ).fromNow()}
        </span>
        <SaveIcon product={product._id} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
);

export default Product;
```

Save redux actions

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import axios from "axios";
import { LOADING, FETCH_SAVE, FETCH_SAVES, ERROR, SAVE_LISTING } from "../type";

const API = process.env.REACT_APP_API;

export const fetchSaves = () => async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOADING
    })
    axios
        .get(`${API}/saves`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_SAVES,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
            toast.error(err.response.data.message)
        })
}

export const fetchSave = productId => async dispatch => {
    axios
        .get(`${API}/save/${productId}`)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_SAVE,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
        })
}

export const saveListing = product => async dispatch => {
    axios
        .post(`${API}/saves`, { product })
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: SAVE_LISTING,
                payload: res.data
            })
            toast.success(res.data.message)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: ERROR,
                payload: err.response.data
            })
            toast.error(err.response.data.message)
        })
}
```

Save reducer

```
import { LOADING, FETCH_SAVES, FETCH_SAVE, SAVE_LISTING } from "../../actions/type";

let initialState = {
    isLoading: false
}

const saveReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type)  {
        case LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading: true
            }
        case FETCH_SAVES:
            return {
                ...state,
                saves: action.payload.saves,
                isLoading: false
            }
        case FETCH_SAVE:
            return {
                ...state,
                saved: action.payload.saved,
                isLoading: false,
                save: action.payload.save
            }
        case SAVE_LISTING:
            return {
                ...state,
                saved: action.payload.saved,
                save: action.payload.save
            }
        default: 
            return{
                ...state
            }
    }
}

export default saveReducer;
```

I expect that when I click on a single listing, on the heart icon, only that listing should turn black

Comment: what does saved and save log in save component ?

Comment: saved is a boolean value that either returns true or false if the listing already exists in the database.
save is an object returned from the database in the save model with a productId and userId
@ibtsam

Answer (score 0):

Ok looking at your I think the save flag that you have should be in your products array I suppose because that's what your are listing, and then you pass the product object to your Save component, then you will do something like

```
    <Icon
      type="heart"
      style={{
        fontSize: "25px",
        padding: "5px",
        marginLeft: "55%",
        color: `${product.saved ? "#000000" : "#ebeaea"}`
      }}
    />
```

then you will have the change of color for the product that you cilcked.
If you see what's happening now save is true for all your products because it's not linked to some product

Hope it helps